# mysql : how to use LIMIT on a basic 1 level hierarchy select?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple database structure with 1 level (a forum like):
Each message can has many answers (parentMessageid)

> message(id, subject, content, usreid, parentMessageid)

```
SELECT message.*
FROM message
LEFT JOIN message AS message2 ON message2.parentMessageid = message.id
```

My goal is now to create a pagination:

ex: **retrieve the 5 messages starting from 10 including ALL the answers**

Something like: (LIMIT 10,5)

So I want to have as final:

10 messages for instance, and ALL their answers

N rows (not defined) but only 10 rows for the parentid=0 (the 5 messages and ALL their answers)

Comment: so all your messages are in 1 table, the message as well as the answers?

Comment: you want to retrieve 5 messages PLUS all the answers to these 5 messages?

Comment: So I want to have as final: N rows (not defined) but only 10 rows for the parentid=0 (the 5 messages and ALL their answers). 
Everything is in 1 table. The joint is on parentMessageid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I have no possibility to check this:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM message AS m,
(SELECT im.* FROM message AS im LIMIT (10, 5)) AS p
WHERE m.id = p.id OR m.parentMessageid = p.id
```